# Проблема с внедрением библиотеки googletrans

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, текст, google-translate

Столкнулся с проблемой замены библиотеки **`translate`** на **`googletrans`**. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
from googletrans import Translator
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
rBtn = IntVar()
root.title('Переводчик')
root.geometry('730x480')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


def translater():
    if (rBtn.get() == 0):
        translator = Translator(from_lang='English', to_lang='Russian')
    elif (rBtn.get() == 1):
        translator = Translator(from_lang='Russian', to_lang='English')
    txt = pole.get('0.0', END)
    w = translator.translate(txt)
    poleTranslate.delete('1.0', END)
    poleTranslate.insert('1.0', w)


pole = Text(root, width=80, height=10, font='Arial, 13')
pole.pack(pady=10)
algo01 = Radiobutton(root, text="Перевод на русский", variable=rBtn, value=0, font='Arial, 12')
algo01.place(x=50, y=215)
Btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Перевести", command=translater)
Btn.pack()
algo02 = Radiobutton(root, text="Перевод на английский", variable=rBtn, value=1, font='Arial, 12')
algo02.place(x=430, y=215)
poleTranslate = Text(root, width=80, height=10, font='Arial, 13')
poleTranslate.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from googletrans import Translator
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
rBtn = IntVar()
root.title('Переводчик')
root.geometry('730x480')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

translator = Translator()                                                 # +++


def translater():
    if (rBtn.get() == 0):
#        translator = Translator(from_lang='English', to_lang='Russian')
        from_lang = 'en'                                                  # +++
        to_lang = 'ru'                                                    # +++
    elif (rBtn.get() == 1):
#        translator = Translator(from_lang='Russian', to_lang='English')
        from_lang = 'ru'                                                  # +++
        to_lang = 'en'                                                    # +++

        
    txt = pole.get('0.0', END)
#    w = translator.translate(txt)
    w = translator.translate(txt, src=from_lang, dest=to_lang)            # +++
    
    poleTranslate.delete('1.0', END)
    poleTranslate.insert('1.0', w.text)                                   # +++ .text


pole = Text(root, width=80, height=10, font='Arial, 13')
pole.pack(pady=10)

algo01 = Radiobutton(root, 
    text="Перевод на русский", variable=rBtn, value=0, font='Arial, 12')
algo01.place(x=50, y=215)

Btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Перевести", command=translater)
Btn.pack()

algo02 = Radiobutton(root, 
    text="Перевод на английский", variable=rBtn, value=1, font='Arial, 12')
algo02.place(x=430, y=215)

poleTranslate = Text(root, width=80, height=10, font='Arial, 13')
poleTranslate.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]